# Why can't I post my question on MO anymore

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts, post-ban

It seems that my account in MO has been  blocked. My post is no more accepted, saying that

> we are no more accepting post from this account.

How can I get my account unblocked?

Comment: Links to some info about question ban (and answer ban) can be found [in the corresponding tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/post-ban/info).

Comment: About the choice of tags: It seems to me that this is closer to ([meta-tag:support]) than to ([meta-tag:discussion]), so probably that tag could be added. Also I don't think that (blacklist) is really the suitable that here, if you [check the tag-excerpt](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/blacklist/info), this tag is intended for " questions about the words and phrases which are blocked from appearing in posts or titles".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason is explained in [this help center article](https://mathoverflow.net/help/question-bans). As the article states, the best step you can take next is to edit your existing questions. Unfortunately, you have several deleted questions with negative scores. But improving extant questions won't hurt. This activity might help you spot ways you could ask new questions more productively too when the ban is lifted.